# Saving order of rows after update

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview, updates

I have a tableView with some rows that are loaded the first time the app launches (if firsttimelaunch method) and after update. The user can move them around in the table. Everything works fine and saving the order with nsuserdefaults is no problem.

But, if I then update the app in the App Store and remove, change or add a row in the table, the app would probably reset the order that the user previously set.

I'm trying to figure out how I can solve that problem, what should I do?
Thanks!

Comment: that's not my question, I know it's saving after the update. But I want to add, remove and change the strings in the array in an update without interfering the users modification of the strings order in the tableview.

Comment: yes but the .plist is different for all users so I can't edit that one right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the app's version number as one of your values in NSUserDefaults and at app launch check the saved version number and update accordingly.